# How can I avoid needing to keep the Arduino Serial Monitor open when sending commands using the php_serial library through PHP/shell?

Tags: php, shell, serial-port, arduino, tail

I am attempting to send serial commands to an [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) through PHP using the [php_serial class](http://code.google.com/p/php-serial/) written by Remy on an Mac OS X machine, and for some reason, it only works when I have the serial monitor from the Arduino program open.

I have tried using a 10 µF capacitor to bridge the reset pin to the ground pin (which should feasibly prevent the auto-reset/DTR pulse that would otherwise cause issues), but still with no success.

Also, when I tail the port, it shows nothing at all on the command line, but it does show responses from the Arduino in the serial monitor if I have it open.

How can I fix this?

I've just about had it with this issue, so I hope someone can help me out...

Comment: Have you set the baud rate correctly when you're reading from the port without the IDE open?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the library.
Only one program at time should be able to use the serial port, so the problem is in the library.
Also he library seems dead since 2010, so just try another library, or start to look for the issue in it

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem in that the `tail -f` command only seems to work when the serial monitor is open.
I'm running the simple digitalRead example on an arduino and if I open a command shell and run `tail -f /dev/tty.usbmodemfd141` while the serial monitor is running, I can see output. As soon as I stop the serial monitor, the output stops.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using pySerial. My serial commands would only work when I had the monitor open. I fixed it by adding a sleep after opening the serial port and before writing to it. I would give that a shot, add in a 1s sleep after using whatever php_serial's open call is before you try to write to it or read it.